# Why the command expo start isn't working?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo, prompt

I'am trying to open my expo project using the nodejs prompt, but I keep getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\Regis\ProjetoFerias>expo start
Starting project at C:\Users\Regis\ProjetoFerias
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
Could not get status from Metro bundler. connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:19001
Connecting to Metro bundler failed.
Error: Connecting to Metro bundler failed.
    at _waitForRunningAsync (C:\@expo\xdl@59.0.10\src\Project.ts:1264:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at startReactNativeServerAsync (C:\@expo\xdl@59.0.10\src\Project.ts:1608:3)
    at Object.startAsync (C:\@expo\xdl@59.0.10\src\Project.ts:1785:5)
    at action (C:\Users\Regis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\start.ts:167:3)
    at C:\Users\Regis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\start.ts:334:16
    at Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Regis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expocli\src\exp.ts:346:7)
```

I've tried to use the command "expo start -c", that cleans the cache, with no sucessfull results:

```
C:\Users\Regis\ProjetoFerias>expo start -c
Starting project at C:\Users\Regis\ProjetoFerias
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
Could not get status from Metro bundler. connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:19001
Connecting to Metro bundler failed.
Error: Connecting to Metro bundler failed.
    at _waitForRunningAsync (C:\@expo\xdl@59.0.10\src\Project.ts:1264:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at startReactNativeServerAsync (C:\@expo\xdl@59.0.10\src\Project.ts:1608:3)
    at Object.startAsync (C:\@expo\xdl@59.0.10\src\Project.ts:1785:5)
    at action (C:\Users\Regis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\start.ts:167:3)
    at C:\Users\Regis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\start.ts:334:16
    at Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Regis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expocli\src\exp.ts:346:7)
```

As you can see, the same error appears (Connecting to Metro bundler failed).

I really don't understand why it's happening. Yesterdey everything on the project was working properly, however today I can't even open the app.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround that i found is to run

```
npm clean --force
```

first and then running

```
expo start -c
```

Also soon after blunder start I clicked "**Run in web browser**"
This workaround avoided above crash for my self.